# Как правильно обработать событие JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется `div id="ui-datepicker-div"`, в котором есть таблица и ссылка с `class='ui-state-default'`. 
Как мне сделать обработку клика по ссылке с  `class='ui-state-default'` именно с текущим `div id="ui-datepicker-div"`:

```html
<div id="ui-datepicker-div">
  <table class="ui-datepicker-calendar">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col" class="ui-datepicker-week-end">
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="3" data-year="2018">
          <a class="ui-state-default" href="#">1</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
```

Такой код не срабатывает:

```
$('.ui-state-default').on('click', function() {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте вложенные селекторы, чтобы указать, что Вас интересует конкретный подэлемент

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#ui-datepicker-div .ui-state-default').click(function() {
    console.log('Click');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ui-datepicker-div">
  <table class="ui-datepicker-calendar">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col" class="ui-datepicker-week-end">
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="3" data-year="2018">
          <a class="ui-state-default" href="#">1</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

А вот такой `$('.ui-state-default').on('click', function() {})` Сработает

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('click', 
  '#ui-datepicker-div td.ui-datepicker-week-end a.ui-state-default', 
  function() { ... });
```